# H323 configuration in FreeSwitch

Tags: voip, freeswitch, h.323

I want to install mod_h323 in FreeSwitch. I have installed the following packages. 
   ptlib-2.8.2 
   h323plus-20100525

Then I have executed the following commands also in the freeswitch source direcory.

make mod_h323-clean
 make mod_h323 
 make mod_h323-install

I have executed the all the above successfully. Then I have started the freeswitch. In that I have checked the mod_h323 module, but it is not installed.

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the module in autoload or manually - load mod_h323 via fs_cli